# Why does Python throw an EOF Error when checking this code?

Tags: python

I take an online Python course, and it checks certain things in your code to grade it. The only check that is currently failing is described as this:
"This test case checks to make sure that the validateDay() function prompts the user to re-enter the day if needed, and returns the day at the end of the function."
It says it fails because it encounters an EOF Error. Whenever I run the code on its own, there are no problems. Could someone explain why it is throwing an error? Here is the code:

```
def validateMonth(month):
    while not (0 < month < 13):
        month = int(input("Invalid month. Please enter value from 1-12: "))
    return(month)
def leap_year(year):
    if ((year % 100 == 0) and (year % 400 == 0)) or (year % 4 == 0):
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)
def validateDay(month, day, year):
    if (month == 1) or (month == 3) or (month == 5) or (month == 7) or (month == 8) or (month == 10) or (month == 12):
        number_of_days = 31
    elif (month == 4) or (month == 6) or (month == 9) or (month == 11):
        number_of_days = 30
    elif (month == 2) and (leap_year(year) == 1):
        number_of_days = 29
    else:
        number_of_days = 28
    while not (0 < day < number_of_days):
        day = int(input("Invalid day. Please enter value from 1-" + str(number_of_days) + ": "))
    return(day)
def printEvents():
    for i in range(len(eventMonth)):
        if eventMonth[i] == 1:
            eventMonth[i] = "January"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 2:
            eventMonth[i] = "February"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 3:
            eventMonth[i] = "March"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 4:
            eventMonth[i] = "April"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 5:
            eventMonth[i] = "May"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 6:
            eventMonth[i] = "June"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 7:
            eventMonth[i] = "July"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 8:
            eventMonth[i] = "August"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 9:
            eventMonth[i] = "September"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 10:
            eventMonth[i] = "October"
        elif eventMonth[i] == 11:
            eventMonth[i] = "November"
        else:
            eventMonth[i] = "December"
    print("List of Events")
    for i in range(len(eventName)):
        print(eventName[i])
        print("Date: " + eventMonth[i], str(eventDay[i]) + ", " + str(eventYear[i]))
def addEvent():
    name = input("What is the event: ")
    year = int(input("What is the year: "))
    month = int(input("What is the month (number): "))
    month = validateMonth(month)
    day = int(input("What is the date: "))
    day = validateDay(month, day, year)
    eventName.append(name)
    eventMonth.append(month)
    eventDay.append(day)
    eventYear.append(year)
 
eventName = []
eventMonth = []
eventDay = []
eventYear = []
addEvent()
while input("Do you want to enter another date? NO to stop: ") == "Yes":
    addEvent()
printEvents()
```

I made sure that all syntax was correct, and to my knowledge, it was. Unfortunately, this didn't change anything. Also, because of the nature of the function, I can't really use try() and except().

Comment: How are you running your code? An EOF error suggests that you're reaching the end of STDIN. That usually doesn't happen if you're running your code interactively from a terminal, unless you specially make your terminal emit EOF.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, since I can't check the testing process, is this line

```
while not (0 < day < number_of_days):
        day = int(input("Invalid day. Please enter value from 1-" + str(number_of_days) + ": "))
```

You could enter `number_of_days` exactly (i.e. 1-28 and the entry is 28) and it would reprompt. This could make it so that the test's expected/actual input windows are not aligned, and if the test includes an EOF at the end it may hit the EOF while it was still expecting inputs.

Comment: I believe this is exactly right.  The grading system provided an input of 28, and the code incorrectly rejected that input and asked for more, but the grading system had no more input remaining in its series of tests, so the error happened.